# When using an if statement with or in Python, is there a way to identify which variable exactly triggered the statement?

Tags: python

If I have something like this:

```
var1 = input("Enter a number lower than or equal to 100")
var2 = input("Enter a number greater than or equal to 1.")
if var1 > 100 or var2 < 1:
    print("Wrong.")
```

How do I figure out whether it was var1 or var2 which caused the program to print wrong, without using another if statement like this:

```
if var1 > 100 or var2 < 1:
    if var1 > 100:
        print("Wrong.")
    if var2 < 1:
        print("Wrong.")
```

Comment: You can't.  You need both `if` statements.

Comment: You dont need the first `if` in the second example though,

Answer (score 3):

You only need two if statements (or for your specific case one `if` and one `elif`) like the following:

```
if var1 > 100:
    print("Wrong.")
elif var2 < 1:
    print("Wrong.")
```

In above code, if `var1` is greater than 100, the first "Wrong" string is printed and the second if statement is not executed (due to the 'else if' statement `elif`). If `var1` is smaller or equal 100 and `var2` smaller 1, then the second print statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages almost universally do not let you do so.

Actually the concept of a variable "triggering" the `if` statement is an abstraction that isn't actually supported by the language at all.  The `if` statement is not triggered by `var1` nor `var2`.  It is "triggered" by the expression `var1 > 100 or var2 < 1`.

You could get away with:

```
var1Triggered = (var1 > 100)
var2Triggered = (var2 < 1)
if var1Triggered or var2Triggered:
    ...
```

you could also play games with something like:

```
trigger = None
if var1 > 100:
    trigger = "var1"
elif var2 < 1:
    trigger = "var2"

if trigger is not None:
    print trigger, " is wrong"
```

However, this brings up the reasons why it's less than ideal to think this way:

- What if both `var1` **and** `var2` "triggered" it?  That can happen
- What if it is unclear what it means for a variable to trigger.  Consider an exclusive or example: `(var1 and not var2) or (not var1 and var2)`.

The general case of what you want cannot be written in any language, due to these issues.  Accordingly, Python, like other languages, chooses not to give you any special syntax for it.  If you really do what that particular behavior, you can code in in multiple if statements, as you wrote in the question.

Comment: Golang sorta does `if i := 2; i > 0 {`